# Syntax error, unexpected end of file php

Tags: php, html

after researching and debugging, i cant seem to find the cause of this error.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>hquirit | Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "id1147793_hquirit";
    $dbname = "id1147793_bukkitplugins";
    $password = "5mHgq9quirr421";

    $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbuser, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$connect) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $query = "SELECT name, downloads, upload_date FROM bukkit_plugins";
    $result = $connect->query($query);

    echo "<div class='container'>";
    echo "<div class=table-responsive'>";
    echo "<table class='table tabled-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Plugin Name</th><th>Downloads</th><th>Upload Date</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['downloads'] . "</td><td>" . $row['upload_date'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

every part of the code works, so when i try to view the page on webhost, an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /storage/ssd2/793/1147793/public_html/bukkit_plugins.php on line 53" comes up (line 53 being the end of the html tag).

Comment: The `while` loop is missing its closing `}`.

Comment: second if loop not close  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  }

Comment: It is clearly saying that to add jQuery library before bootstrap.

Comment: use NetBeans editor it shows error if any loop is not close or any Syntex errors. This tool is great for coding.

Comment: Always have these silly mistakes thanks for the spot!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['downloads'] . "</td><td>" . $row['upload_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

You haven't close if loop that's why getting error....

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
echo "<tbody>";
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['downloads'] . "</td><td>" . $row['upload_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</tbody>";



  to  

    echo "<tbody>";
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['downloads'] . "</td><td>" . $row['upload_date'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
              }
            }
    echo "</tbody>";
```

You just forgot a "}" before tbody print.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap needs Tether, so you need to include tether.min.js before you include bootstrap.min.js

Try adding these two lines before bootstrap.min.js

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>

Comment: How does js library connected with php syntax error?

Comment: The first error I found was of bootstrap! At second point it is the error of PHP "}".